# Need help in Radix sort

Tags: python, radix-sort

I am having a problem in creating a list 
I am done with the logic part for radix sort . 
Here is the code:

```
import math

a = [4, 15, 7, 3, 6, 22, 45, 82]

a1 = [[] for _ in xrange(len(a))]
a2 = [[] for _ in xrange(len(a))]
a3 = [[] for _ in xrange(len(a))]
a4 = [[] for _ in xrange(len(a))]
b = [[] for _ in xrange(10)]
b2 = [[] for _ in xrange(10)]
d=len(str(max(a)))



[str(item).zfill(d) for item in a]

print a
```

this part of the code will add zero before the numbers so that length of all the digits will be same as that of no having max no of digit

it gives `a = [ 04 , 15 , 07 , 03 , 06 , 22 , 45 , 82 ]`

```
for x in xrange(0,len(a)) :
   a1[x].append(a[x]%10)
   print a1 

print '\n'
```

this will save the end digit of each numbers 
as follows

```
a1 = [[4], [5], [7], [3], [6], [2], [5], [2]]
```

In the next part ,if bucket no matches with the end digits of the no.
then the no. having that digit will be stored in it.

```
i=0
for x in xrange(0,len(a)) :    
  for u in range(0,len(a)) :
    if a1[u]==[i] :
      b[x].append(a[u])
  i=i+1


for u in range(0,len(a)) :
   print b[u]
```

Output will be as follows :

```
[]
[]
[22, 82]
[3]
[4]
[15, 45]
[6]
[7]
```

This part will pick up the no. from the bucket starting from bucket no. zero to bucket no. 10

```
for k in range(0,len(a))  :      
 l=len(b[k])
 for t in range(0,l) :
     a2[k]=b[k][t]
     print a2[k]
```

a2 is

```
22
82
3
4
15
45
6
7
```

but when i print it ,like this-

```
print a2[0]
```

It gives

```
[]
```

I don't want to store the empty values in that a2 list
How to avoid it?

I know i have to use condition like "if bucket is empty dont put the no just continue the loop" 
I dont know how to write code for this.

I guess i need to add

```
if len(b[k][t])==0 :
       continue
else :
    a2[k]=b[k][t]
    print a2[k]
```

But it's not working

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 39, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Can we have the content of line 39?

Comment: line 39: if len(b[k][t])==0 :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `b[?]` is an array of integers, so `b[k][t]` will be an integer, but you are trying to take its length in `if len(b[k][t])==0:`.

The only way to avoid having empty elements of `a2` is to not use an array; for example, a dictionary.

Comment: I don't know how to write a code to avoid adding empty values in a2.i need help in that part

Comment: i am still not getting it

Comment: Now i got it 
`e=0
for k in range(0,len(a))  :      
 l=len(b[k])
 for t in range(0,l) :
     a2[k]=b[k][t]
     e=e+1
 print a2`

need to write 
`a2=[none] * 8`